# Chakra-ui ignores FontWeight on Firefox

Tags: reactjs, firefox, chakra-ui

I have text with assigned `fontWeight` values in chakra-ui/react. But since a few days firefox simply ignores the `fontWeight` property on the text. I build an example on codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/font-error-sample-o77kk?file=/src/App.js).

**Expected result and result in chrome:**

[image]

**Result in Firefox & Firefox developer edition:**
[image]

Does anyone knows why Firefox behaves like this?

```js
<Text fontWeight="bold" fontSize="2xl">
    This is a sample text.
</Text>
```

The same deployed website looks totally different on each browser...

**EDIT:**
This seems to be not a chakra-ui issue, even the `fontWeight` here in my StackOverflow post is ignored.

Comment: If you've been able to implement a work-around, I'd be interested to see it. Thank you

Comment: @Dylan Unfortunately not. Still having this issue when using chakra-ui. also appears when using chrome in private mode.